# Characterization of capability-based security in Isabelle/HOL

Tags: isabelle, isabelle-hol

I am looking for a formal characterization of [Capability-based security](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capability-based_security) in Isabelle/HOL using a **set of invariants** that "is complete". I'm not exactly sure what "complete" means, and I'm also not sure if my starting point makes sense:

```
theory Capability_Security
imports Main
begin

type_synonym user_id = nat
type_synonym object_id = nat
type_synonym capability = "user_id × object_id ⇒ bool"

definition is_valid_cap :: "user_id ⇒ object_id ⇒ capability ⇒ bool" where
"is_valid_cap uid oid cap ≡ cap (uid, oid)"

definition can_access :: "user_id ⇒ object_id ⇒ capability ⇒ bool" where
"can_access uid oid cap ≡ ∃owner. is_valid_cap owner oid cap ∧
  (owner = uid ∨ cap (uid, owner))"

definition secure_system :: "capability set ⇒ bool" where
"secure_system caps ≡ ∀uid oid1 oid2 cap1 cap2. is_valid_cap uid oid1 cap1 ∧
  is_valid_cap uid oid2 cap2 ∧ oid1 ≠ oid2 ∧ ¬can_access uid oid2 cap1 ∧
  ¬can_access uid oid1 cap2 ⟶ ¬(cap1 = cap2)"
```

I'm not sure if above is enough, but I'd be glad for any hints or pointers that might allow me to make progress. Thanks!

---

One thing I'm specifically after (well, if the definitions make sense) are invariants that are commonly agreed to be necessary and sufficient, such as

```
theorem access_monotonicity:
  assumes "secure_system caps"
  assumes "can_access uid oid cap"
  assumes "cap ⊆ cap'"
  shows "can_access uid oid cap'"
```

This invariant states that if a user can access an object with a given capability, they can also access the object with a superset of that capability. This invariant is important because it ensures that if a user has access to an object, they can also access the object with a more permissive capability.

Comment: It might help to ask a more general question: what are some formalizations of security in Isabelle/HOL? I am sure there are some, but I don't know any specifically. There ought to be people around here who do.

Comment: yeah, _any_ formalization in Isabelle/HOL of _any_ security model (eg RBAC or other) would probably help! and _any_ formalization (in sth different than Isabelle/HOL) of capability-based security as well. if only a commonly used/agreed list of invariants that capability-based security must fulfil.

Comment: I'd start digging for security-related content in the [Archive of Formal Proofs](https://www.isa-afp.org/topics/computer-science/security/).

Comment: seL4's access control system is based on capabilities, [here](https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download;jsessionid=0A87947A226039B6D4CEFACAFF5E628A?doi=10.1.1.71.7043&rep=rep1&type=pdf) is a high-level overview which may be of interesting.